# Generating list of feature classes from .gdb file using ArcPy Idle script: Error thrown

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, idle, describe-feature-type

I'm new to ArcPy and Python and have a very simple question. I'm trying to write a Python script in `idle` to extract the number of feature class files from a geodatabase. I can do it just fine in the console, but when I try to write a script, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ihb\Documents\assignmente_7.py", line 22, in <module>
    for feature in fcList:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Here is the code that is generating the error:

```
#Import arcpy and set output environments
import arcpy, sys
from arcpy import env
print "Please enter desired workspace in the 'Args' space: "
if sys.modules['idlelib']: sys.argv.extend(raw_input("Args: ").split())
workSpace = sys.argv[1]
env.workspace = workSpace
env.overwriteOutput = True

#Get Feature Classes
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for feature in fcList: ### <-- **ERROR OCCURS HERE** <--####
    desc = arcpy.Describe(feature)
    print feature
```

I need to include the `sys` argument so that users can specify the workspace directory.

Comment: It doesn't appear that your problem is GIS-related. You should be checking that the `sys.argv[1]` value is valid before using it to set the workspace.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Did @Vince solve your issue?

Comment: @Aaron yes he did, thank you! I was putting my workspace directory in quotation marks, and I just found out you don't do that sys.argv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I was using quotation marks to specify my workspace directory. That was my issue. You can't do that with sys.argv, apparently. I'm new to Python, so I'm learning as I go!